# Continuous shake in corona

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk, accelerometer

I have a game in Corona. In which I have shake event implemented. Now I want to keep the bottle shaking in the game till I keep shaking the device. Whereas, it stops the shake animation when the hardware shake stops after once even if I keep shaking the device continuously.

```
if(event.isShake)then
    shakeTimer = timer.performWithDelay(20,incrementMeter,-1)
    shakeIsDone = true
elseif(event.isShake == false)then
    timer.performWithDelay(1000,afterShakeStop)
end
```

Comment: Could you include a little more code? How are you using the shakeIsDone variable? When are you "resetting" this variable? We need to know a little more to be able to help you. Perhaps include more code?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the variable "shakeIsDone" to true once the first shake event is registered and you are not changing this "state" back when the shake state changes?

I am going to assume a few things here since your question is a bit vague. I am assuming you are using the shakeIsDone variable to know when you aren't shaking the device and that this variable is also used to make the animation shake.

What you should want is rather to do the animation directly from the shake event; so that when you shake the device you directly shake the animation.

First you should add the method

As such:

```
-- The function Corona calls when the accelerometer detects a shake.
local function onShake (event)
    if event.isShake then
    -- Enter animation code here
    end
end

--Establish a eventlistener for the onShake 
Runtime:addEventListener("accelerometer", onShake)
```

Comment: I agree with your suggestion @Frozire.

Comment: Sorry for not describing the question in a proper form. Actually, my question is a contradictory composition of three situations:

Comment: Sorry, for not describing the question in a proper form. Actually, my question is a contradictory composition of three situations. In game, I have a cocktail shaker that I want to shake till the device shakes. And screen should go off once shake is stopped.      Problems I am facing:                                               - Device configures the shake only once(for its default number of seconds). This happens when I do it the same way as I wrote earlier - If I don't use if-else and check shake only, I don't get the situation when the device stopped shaking.